# How to set selected attribute on option after filter query?

Tags: wp-query, filters, wp-admin, admin, dropdown

I am working on an admin filter for a custom post type and have it mostly working. However, I'm stuck on one point. How can I keep the selected option visible to the user after the filter query?

I've looked at `wp_dropdown_categories` (which I used in a different filter) and it doesn't seem to fit my case. In this case, the filter is against a database query. This is what I have so far.

```
function filter_forms_by_status() {
  global $post_type;
  global $wpdb;

  if ($post_type != 'request_form') {
    return;
  } else {
    $query = "
        SELECT DISTINCT post_name
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE 'request_status'
    ";

    $result = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_N);
    $field_object = get_field_object($result[0]);
    $status_array = $field_object['choices'];

    echo "<select class='postform' id='status-filter' name='status'>";
    foreach ($status_array as $status_key => $status) {
      echo "<option value=$status_key>$status</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
  }
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_forms_by_status');

function query_posts_by_status($query) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php') {
    $request_status = $_GET['status'];
    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'request_status';
    $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $request_status;
  }
  return $query;
};
add_filter('parse_query', 'query_posts_by_status');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it's not the prettiest way to solve this, but this is what I came up with. Using a combination of session storage and a little javascript.

First - I added `session_start()` to the beginning of my file. Then in `query_posts_by_status` I added `$_SESSION['request_status'] = $request_status`. This gave me access to the global `$_SESSION` variable. Last, I added a little javascript as follows to `filter_forms_by_status`.

```
<script>
  var statusFilter = document.getElementById('status-filter');
  var filter = "<?php echo $_SESSION['request_status'] ?>";
  statusFilter.value = filter;
</script>
```

So, my complete solution for this case is...

```
start_session(); // at top of file.
function filter_forms_by_status() {
    global $post_type;
    global $wpdb;

    if ($post_type != 'request_form') {
        return;
    } else {
        $query = "
            SELECT DISTINCT post_name
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title LIKE 'request_status'
        ";

        $result = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_N);
        $field_object = get_field_object($result[0]);
        $status_array = $field_object['choices'];

        echo "<select class='postform' id='status-filter' name='status'>";
        foreach ($status_array as $status_key => $status) {
            echo "<option value=$status_key>$status</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
    ?>
        <script>
            var statusFilter = document.getElementById('status-filter');
            var filter = "<?php echo $_SESSION['request_status'] ?>";
            statusFilter.value = filter;
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_forms_by_status');

function query_posts_by_status($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php') {
        $request_status = $_GET['status'];

        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'request_status';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $request_status;
        $_SESSION['request_status'] = $request_status;
    }
    return $query;
};
add_filter('parse_query', 'query_posts_by_status');
```